# regular expression for number with decimal places

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone help me build javscript regular expression to validate 6 digit number with 2 deimal places?
These examples should pass the test

```
0,  0.0,  0.33,  1, 11,  111, 1111, 11111,  111111
1.33, 1.3, 12.33, 12.3, 123.0, 123.33, 1234.0, 1234.11
```

tried this:

```
/^\d{1,4}(\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

but it fails in jquery when .(dot) is pressed

Comment: @Swapnil why you wrote `\d{1,4}`? Is there at most 6 digit numbers before decimal? Or totally 6 digits including those after decimal point?

Comment: sorry it should be \d{1,6}

Comment: your requirements are not clear, you are missing a lot of edge cases and your accepted answer is wrong. Take a look into my fiddles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press dot there are no digits after it yet and your regexp fails. So you can try this regexp `/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{0,2})?$/` to allow this situation, but be aware that user would be able to enter numbers like this `12345.`

Comment: @Hui Zheng, `1.` is ok when user enters number. In the initial task the system checks user's input on fly, so it should allow user to enter dot without showing error and blocking ability to enter next digits.

Comment: @Christoph, I don't agree with your 'fail:' section. `01.11, 1.` are ok. `22222.11` may be ok because it is not fully clear in the task '6 digit number with 2 deimal places' means 'only 6 digit for full number' or '6 digits for integer part and 2 digits after dot'

Comment: @pstr Actually OP didn't make it clear that the regex should *allow* any string entered in the middle of typing, instead of the final string. Now I understand why he accepted your answer, no wonder he kept saying "fails when .(dot) is **pressed**".

Answer (score 3):

Try regex: `/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`. Note: you need escape dot.

If what you require is the total number of digits(including those after decimal point) is at most 6, then regex will be: `/^(?!.{8,})\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`. The expression adds a *negative lookahead* `?!.{8,}`, which will exclude those digits having length larger than 7.

Update:
As @Christoph pointed out, "01.23" should be excluded, then the above two expressions should be `/^([1-9]\d{0,5}|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$/` and `/^(?!.{8,})([1-9]\d{0,5}|0)(\.\d{1,2})?$/` respectively.

Comment: +1 looks good except for one flaw (if you consider it as such) http://jsfiddle.net/cEeTa/

Comment: As per your requirement, this regex could accept at most two digits after dot. Right? I'm confused. Besides, should the total number of digits be less than 6?

Comment: @Christoph You mean my regex matches on 01.11 which should not, right?  This depends on more detailed requirement, as OP hasn't exclude that explicitly.

Comment: @Christoph I updated my answer, now it should pass all of your test.

Comment: good work make;) well, of course it is dependent on what the OP wants, but he didn't state it clearly enough for sure.

Answer (score 0):

DOT is a special character and needs to be escaped. You should use "\."

The easiest would be to first check that the length of the String is less than 7 (6 digits and 1 dot) using an appropriate jquery function. That deals with the length.

Then for the regex, you just need to check that it has at most 2 decimal places which you could do with this: `/^\d{1,6}(\.\d{1,2})?$/`

http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html

Comment: so can you please give me regular expression which will work as I am very poor at it. Thanks In Advance.